# Search REGEX value in text

Tags: java, regex

I'm creating this method to search the text only for the Service Order number, this information can come anywhere in the text because it is an open field for typing, I only need the first value found if you have more than one service order.
example text:

> Please check **service order number 1-202012345678** for vehicle repair toyota Corolla red

Could someone help me find the error?

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Encontra_Ordem {

    private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile(".*([1@][-@]\\d{12}).*"); 

    public static String buscaordemnotexto(String texto) {
        String valor = "";
        Matcher matcher = PATTERN.matcher(texto);
        if(matcher.matches() && matcher.groupCount() == 1){
            String numerodaordem = matcher.group(1);
            valor += numerodaordem;

        } 
        return valor;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the input and format of service order number. Does the format of all service order number will be like this one i.e. 1-202012345678?

Comment: As per you example: [this](https://regex101.com/r/X8GHDW/1) regex works fine.

Comment: You need to use `find()` instead of `matches()`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel there is more to it. Please read Op's comment. He wants **only the first occurrence** of the service order number.

Comment: @Mandy8055 then you still need to use `find()`, not `matches()`.

Comment: Right!!!I am not denying that. I'm telling there is more to the requirement.

Comment: Hello @Fabio Eto
I was wondering if you had time to check my answer.
If you find it useful please upvote it and / or mark it as final answer, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

With the given data I'd suggest this solution:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Encontra_Ordem {

    private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\b\\d-\\d{12}\\b");

    public static String buscaordemnotexto(String texto) {
        String valor = "";
        Matcher matcher = PATTERN.matcher(texto);
        if (matcher.find()) { 
            String numerodaordem = matcher.group();
            valor += numerodaordem;
        }
        return valor;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(buscaordemnotexto("asda sd asd asd asd  sa 2-202012345678 ttttttt 1-202012345678"));
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
2-202012345678
```

**Explanation**

Here's the breakdown of the RegEx I wrote (click on it to make it more readable):
[image: Courtesy of https://regexr.com]

I also used matcher.find() inside an if block so that the content of matcher.group() will be the first RegEx match.

> **The find() Method**
>
> Put simply, the find() method tries to find the
>   occurrence of a regex pattern within a given string. If multiple
>   occurrences are found in the string, then the first call to find()
>   will jump to the first occurrence. Thereafter, each subsequent call to
>   the find() method will go to the next matching occurrence, one by one.

*Sources*

- https://regexr.com
- https://www.baeldung.com/java-matcher-find-vs-matches

Comment: This solution does not work as expected. OP asked to get the first value of service order number. Please have a look at [this](https://onlinegdb.com/S1_wMBjF8) run result from your code

Comment: Its fine now. Just to make it a more efficient remove the unwanted capturing group. This should be fine: `\\b\d-\d{12}\\b`.

Comment: Spot on, @Mandy8055! Thanks for the lesson here, appreciate it :)

Comment: Could you add an explanation to your answer why and how your code solves the problem?

Comment: Sure thing @MarkRotteveel

Comment: Hi @Fábio Eto please consider upvoting my answer and / or selecting it as final answer if it was helpful for you. Thanks!